# Isn't the term bully pulpit an oxymoron?

Tags: meaning, etymology, oxymoron

**bully pulpit**:

A public office or position of authority that provides its occupant with an outstanding opportunity to speak out on any issue.

**bully:**

A person who uses strength or power to harm or intimidate those who are weaker.

Oxford Dictionaries.com

**Pulpit:**

a medium for expressing an opinion, such as a column in a newspaper

http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pulpit

I know the word **bully**, originally, had positive connotations, and progressively deteriorated through fine fellow to harasser of the weak. (Etymonline)

It's not very clear though when  the term lost its positive sense.

Comment: So you're positing that 'bully' had essentially lost its original sense by the year 1---, say, and that 'bully pulpit' now had to be termed an oxymoron (assuming the compound was used at that time)? The root question is surely the switching of senses of 'bully'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A glance at the OED is instructive. *Bully* as a term of endearment continued into the 19th century. But from the late 17th century the modern notion of a *bully* as someone who terrorises the weak, has been around - sense 3a.

Comment: An interesting article on the subject here: http://www.huffingtonpost.com/warren-j-blumenfeld/bully-pulpit_b_4479399.html

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why would a [public] platform for expressing one's views be an oxymoron to the status of exerting one's opinions on others?

Answer (score 2):

In the case of the term 'Bully Pulpit', it's helpful to keep the etymology of the phrase in mind. It was coined by [Theodore Roosevelt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Roosevelt), who used the term to describe the power of the office of the presidency to advocate for an agenda and sway public opinion.

> "I suppose my critics will call that preaching, but I have got such a bully pulpit!"

TR was *notorious* for his fondness for the word 'bully' as an adjective [referring to excellence,](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bully#bully-2) and in this case, he was doing so quite plainly.

While the definition of *bully* has evolved to deprecate this usage, the phrase *Bully Pulpit* has survived, and has come to expand to refer to the persuasive power carried by holders of public office in general.